# Customize approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i wanted to customize the built in approval workflow in such a way that

at present we have to mention the due date and the reviewer and approver in the workflow itself. i want it to be mentioned when we upload a document in the library because it would not be the same reviewer and approver for all the documents in the library. the same is with due date

another thing which i wanted was a descriptive information of what is happening at each stage of the workflow, at present it can be seen in workflow history, but is there any other way by which the participants would be able to view it

and the third thing is when we assign a task to the first person in the group, i want a condition where he can say that he isnt working presently on it. right now the options are approve. reject, change request , when he says he is not working all the participants should be notified.

i have checked through customization of approval workflow, but did not get much of an idea, if anybody could help it would be great thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to write a custom approval wf using SPD
A good video is here

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/video-create-an-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-VA101897477.aspx